# How to multicol a chapter (and its sections etc.) in table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, tocbasic

Since the second chapter only contains short sections etc. I would like to have *only* chapter two  multicolumned.

With `BeforeStartingTOC[toc]{\begin{multicols}{2}} \AfterStartingTOC[toc]{\end{multicols}}` I only get the whole table of contents two columned.

This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside=false,listof=totoc,listof=leveldown]{scrbook}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
  % \BeforeStartingTOC[toc]{\begin{multicols}{2}}
  % \AfterStartingTOC[toc]{\end{multicols}}
  \tableofcontents
  \chapter{long long long long long long long long long long long chapter}
  \section{long long long long long long long long long long long section}  
  \section{long long long long long long long long long long long section}  
  \section{long long long long long long long long long long long section}  
\chapter{short chapter}
\section{short section}
\section{short section}
\section{short section}
\section{short section}
\section{short section}
\section{short section}
\section{short section}
\section{short section}
\section{short section}
\section{short section}
\section{short section}
\section{short section}

  \chapter{long long long long long long long long long long long chapter}
  \section{long long long long long long long long long long long section}  
  \section{long long long long long long long long long long long section}  
  \section{long long long long long long long long long long long section}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `\addtocontents`:

```
\documentclass[twoside=false,listof=totoc,listof=leveldown]{scrbook}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
  % \BeforeStartingTOC[toc]{\begin{multicols}{2}}
  % \AfterStartingTOC[toc]{\end{multicols}}
  \tableofcontents
  \chapter{long long long long long long long long long long long chapter}
  \section{long long long long long long long long long long long section}  
  \section{long long long long long long long long long long long section}  
  \section{long long long long long long long long long long long section}  
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\begin{multicols}{2}}
\chapter{short chapter}
\section{short section}
\section{short section}
\section{short section}
\section{short section}
\section{short section}
\section{short section}
\section{short section}
\section{short section}
\section{short section}
\section{short section}
\section{short section}
\section{short section}
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\end{multicols}}

  \chapter{long long long long long long long long long long long chapter}
  \section{long long long long long long long long long long long section}  
  \section{long long long long long long long long long long long section}  
  \section{long long long long long long long long long long long section}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Imho better looking:

```
\documentclass[twoside=false,listof=totoc,listof=leveldown]{scrbook}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
  % \BeforeStartingTOC[toc]{\begin{multicols}{2}}
  % \AfterStartingTOC[toc]{\end{multicols}}
  \tableofcontents
  \chapter{long long long long long long long long long long long chapter}
  \section{long long long long long long long long long long long section}  
  \section{long long long long long long long long long long long section}  
  \section{long long long long long long long long long long long section}  
\chapter{short chapter}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\bgroup\protect\multicolsep=0pt\protect\begin{multicols}{2}}
\section{short section}
\section{short section}
\section{short section}
\section{short section}
\section{short section}
\section{short section}
\section{short section}
\section{short section}
\section{short section}
\section{short section}
\section{short section}
\section{short section}
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\end{multicols}\protect\egroup}

  \chapter{long long long long long long long long long long long chapter}
  \section{long long long long long long long long long long long section}  
  \section{long long long long long long long long long long long section}  
  \section{long long long long long long long long long long long section}  
\end{document}
```

[image]